# Slider preventing Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever I try to add a automatic slider for recent posts, my drop down menu stops working properly as no sub-menus are displayed.

Here is the website: http://www.abcdfootball.com

Here are two automatic sliders I am trying to use which does not let the drop down function properly:

Slider Code (Which is currently installed in the blog):

```
<style scoped="" type="text/css">
/*
Made by AllBloggerTricks.com with lot of hardwork please keep the comment intact
*/
ul.abt-sidebar-slider *{-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider{font:normal normal 11px Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider,ul.abt-sidebar-slider li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;position:relative}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider{width:100%;height:500px}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider li{height:24.5%;position:absolute;padding:0;width:49.5%;float:left;overflow:hidden;display:none}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider li:nth-child(1),ul.abt-sidebar-slider li:nth-child(2),ul.abt-sidebar-slider li:nth-child(3),ul.abt-sidebar-slider li:nth-child(4){display:block}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider img{border:0;width:100%;height:100%}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider li:nth-child(1){width:100%;height:49.5%;margin:0 0 2px;left:0;top:0}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider li:nth-child(2){left:0;top:50%}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider li:nth-child(3){left:50.5%;top:50%}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider li:nth-child(4){width:100%;left:0;top:75%}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider  .overlayx,ul.abt-sidebar-slider li{-webkit-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;-ms-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;transition:all .4s ease-in-out}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider .overlayx{width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;z-index:2;left:0;top:0;background-image:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FtnGJHMcWH8/UIV3IE-aaJI/AAAAAAAAGHs/WvLypnWxg5A/s1600/linebg-fade.png);background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:repeat-x}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider .overlayx,ul.abt-sidebar-slider img{border:4px solid #2E8DCE;-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider li:nth-child(1) .overlayx{background-position:50% 25%}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider .overlayx:hover{-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft. Alpha(Opacity=10)";filter:alpha(opacity=10);-khtml-opacity:0.1;-moz-opacity:0.1;opacity:0.1}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider h4{position:absolute;bottom:30px;z-index:2;color:white;margin:0;width:100%;padding:0 10px;line-height:1.5em;font-family:Georgia,Times,"Times New Roman";font-weight:normal}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider li:nth-child(1) h4,ul.abt-sidebar-slider li:nth-child(4) h4{font-size:150%}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider .label_text{position:absolute;bottom:10px;left:10px;z-index:2;color:white;font-size:90%}
ul.abt-sidebar-slider li:nth-child(2) .autname,ul.abt-sidebar-slider li:nth-child(3) .autname{display:none}
.buttons{margin:5px 0 0}
.buttons a{display:inline-block;text-indent:-9999px;width:15px;height:25px;position:relative}
.buttons a::before{content:"";width:0;height:0;border-width:8px 7px;border-style:solid;border-color:transparent #535353 transparent transparent;position:absolute;top:50%;margin-top:-8px;margin-left:-10px;left:50%}
.buttons a.nextx::before{border-color:transparent transparent transparent #535353;margin-left:-3px}
</style>
<div id="featuredpostside"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76401970/All%20Blogger%20Tricks/abt-sidebar-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
FeaturedPostSide({
blogURL:"http://www.abcdfootball.com",
MaxPost:8,
idcontaint:"#featuredpostside",
ImageSize:300,
interval:5000,
autoplay:true,
tagName:false
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Open the console, I see is that your jqueries are conflicting

Comment: so what are the fixes? Could you give me any alternative code to use for the slider? Sorry, I am not good in jquery or css. :(